# views contextual filter based on post form data

Tags: views

I'm hoping someone can steer me in the right direction here.

I have view based on a content type. The content type contains a 'keyword' field and pieces of content all have keywords, say for example 'cars', 'trucks' or 'vans'.

The user fills out a form and submits to a page that displays the view in a block. I want the view to retrieve the keyword from the form, and filter the content based on that.

I thought I would be able to do this with PHP validation code in the contextual filter, but now I find that it must return only 'true' or 'false', I can't pass the value from the form and match it to my keyword field.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or useful posting on this? Is it even possible?

Comment: A lot of stuff I'm seeing suggests this could be easily done if the value were in the URL, but it isn't. This is %_POST form data, and I need to match it to a specific field as other keywords will also appear that I don't want.

Comment: maybe hook_views_query_alter() is the way to go here?